# Run php script at scedule using Linux server shell command

Tags: php, linux, bash, apache, shell

My Linux server runs PHP and Apache. I want to run a `.php` file every day at a certain time. (Which will be run automatically in the server)

I have two files: `mail.php` which sends mail to **myEmail@gmail.com**. And `bash.php` which contains some codes which calls `mail.php`.

`bash.php` contains :

```
<?php
    #!/usr/bin/php
    $command="52 14 * * * ./mail.php";
    $result=shell_exec($command);
    echo "<pre>$result</pre>"
?>
```

Then I run `bash.php` in the browser.

I get no error message. But don't receive any email. Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do it this way, All you have to do is to open the Cronjob config file using the command crontab -e, and then add the command line in it:

```
52 14 * * *  <path to>php <Full absolute Path>/mail.php
```

To know your php path use the command:

```
Which php
```

For more details you may refer to the link: [Crontab Command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm)

Comment: In my `Ubuntu` PC I run code in terminal. But in Linux server is there any terminal where I will run `corntab -e` command? Where to write `corntab -e` command ?

Comment: Yes for sure, refer to your hosting provider or system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write a cron job in php.

Throw your bash.php away and convert it to a cron task (crontab -e).

php_mailer.cron:

```
52 14 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/mail.php
```